# How do I configure automapper to only map primitive properties, and not perform any 'calculated' mappings

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, automapper

I use automapper to create my Dtos in entity framework. I have entities with a lot of properties, so this is handy - also, the ProjectTo allows me to easily get the properties I want, often excluding columns with lots of big text fields - so I find it efficient.

When I need to save my Dto, I obviously need to perform the reverse. First I used reversemap, but changed to explicitly configuring the CreateMap because of issues with objects and lists doing unexpected things to calculated fields - totally logical things, but not what I was after.

With this reverse mapping, I am still getting the odd issue with an object trying to map back. As I already have the Id mapping, the entity FK object is not required anyway. For now I just put an ignore on the property and that sorts it, but I would like a more generic solution.

1. Is it possible to configure AutoMapper so that it only maps primitive types (e.g. no objects). I can't leave the objects out, because they are necessary for the forward mapping. They just arent necessary for the reverse.
2. Is there any special sauce for completely disabling flattening? If the property names don't match exactly, I don't want any mapping to take place.

Comment: You can write your own `ReverseMap` and use `ForAllMembers` to ignore what you want. The only way to disable the naming convention is to write one that doesn't match anything.